# AWS ECR pull-through-cache fetch image via HTTP request to registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, curl, ecr

I've set up an AWS ECR pull-through-cache for Docker Hub registry.

Say it is available under: `123.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docker`.

Now after authenticating using:
`aws ecr get-login-password ... | docker login 123.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com -u AWS --password-stdin` I can do something like `docker pull 123.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docker/library/busybox:latest`.

This all makes sense, but my question is how does this work under the hood, because if I do a HTTP request using:

```
curl -vv -H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n AWS:$(aws ecr get-login-password ...) | base64 -w 8000)" -v https://123.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v2/docker/library/busybox/manifests/latest
```

I get
`{"errors":[{"code":"MANIFEST_UNKNOWN","message":"Requested image not found"}]}`

or to be more precise the first time I get an error but after invoking `docker pull` (and I can see that the image was cached on ECR) it starts working.

I've read https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/v1.0.1/spec.md and still don't understand this. What does the official docker client do that is different than my HTTP request that forces ECR to actually pull the image and start caching it?
Is it related to docker authentication - but how does `docker` signal what tag exactly it will request later?

Because after it is cached the normal protocol appears to work (I didn't actually download all the blobs, but at least manifests returns a proper response - HTTP 200 with `layers`). But as mentioned just requesting the same URL the first time returns HTTP 404. And I've also tried to wait a bit - no luck, my request appears to never start the process of ECR downloading the image, despite trying to add User-Agent headers, changing HTTP requests to HEAD etc etc.

Comment: And just to clarify it is not a purely academic question (altho I am very curious what actually goes on), my use case is that I want to expose that ECR endpoint through a reverse proxy to internal users - so they can use `docker pull docker.internal/docker/library/busybox:latest`. The fun fact here is that the behavior here is the same and also a request through official docker client doesn't make ECR cache the image, but if I manually do so (by using docker client on ecr endpoint address) it actually works also through the proxy.

Comment: Suggest you edit your post to add all relevant information, rather than adding comments that people are less likely to read.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I believe context is important but this doesn't add any relevant information, it's just a clearification on why I would want to do it - I hope it should be possible to answer without that. Of course if the outcome will be that more information is needed or that my use case could be better solved in a different way I will amend my question, but for now it is a very narrow technical question - I want to understand what is going on primarily.